# Why does this always result in try?

Tags: java, validation, equality, palindrome

Im writing this java code for school.  I need to see if the data is a palindrome or not and then let the user know the results.  My eyes are bleeding.  I can't figure this out!

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import helpers.*;

public class Palindrome {
    public static boolean check(String dataInput) { 
        boolean test = false;
        String reverseDataInput = new StringBuffer(dataInput).reverse().toString();
        if (dataInput == reverseDataInput){
            test=true;
            return test;
        }
        return test;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputString = "";
        int number = 0;
        boolean isPalindrome = false;       

        number = helpers.InputUtilities.getIntegerInput(inputString, -99999, 99999);

        String str = Integer.toString(number);
        isPalindrome = check(str);
        if (isPalindrome = true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str + " is a palindrome!", "Area", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, str + " is not a palindrome!", "Area", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? I bet it has something to do with `if (isPalindrome = true)` having a single `=` and not `==`.

Comment: When checking String equality use .equals(), not ==

Comment: there is no try block

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder ten years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First java `String`s are compared with `.equals()` not `==` because they are objects (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)).

```
if (dataInput.equals(reverseDataInput))
```

Second your `if` statement is a bit wrong.

```
if (isPalindrome = true){
```

Instead

```
if (isPalindrome == true){
```

or (this looks better to some people)

```
if (isPalindrome){
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  Sorry it was so simple.  I wouldn't have thought to check for the == so although it was posted before, I feel like I needed help.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this question before (here: [Local variable not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15605079/local-variable-not-used/15605278#15605278)).

The problem is simply the `if`: statement. Replace

```
if (isPalindrome = true)
```

with

```
if (isPalindrome)
```

You also need to modify your first `if`:

```
if (dataInput == reverseDataInput)
```

by

```
if (dataInput.equals(reverseDataInput))
```

Because `==` checks for pointer equality and since you generate a new string, the two strings are not the same, they are equal, but not the same...